# React Native TextInput displays only part of text

Tags: react-native

Using this simple code (see [runnable snack](https://snack.expo.io/i0yjIgh_o))

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <TextInput style={styles.paragraph} value={'ios-only! abc-def 242343535325342534523'} />
     <TextInput style={styles.paragraph} value={'ios-only! abc-def 242343535325342534523'} />
   </View>
 );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
   backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
   padding: 8,
 },
 paragraph: {
   margin: 24,
   fontSize: 18,
   textAlign: 'left',
   backgroundColor: 'green',
 },
});
```

I obtain this: You see that part of the text is not visible in the textinput, but becomes visible when I place cursor into the textinput.

Is there some way to display full text content in textinput (and cut it off when it goes offscreen)? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Could be related to this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21969.

Comment: turns out the reproduction here wasn't the issue we were experiencing; for us it was a `flex: 1` problem.